# Bit logic in SQL

Tags: c#, sql

In C# I use to check the boolean gates like this

bool isValid= 3 & 1;

i.e whether 1 is contained in 3 or not. It comes true. as 3 has both the numbers 1 and 2 . My series continues as 2 raise to the power of n i.e 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128.. I need to check the same logic in SQL i.e I will pass the total and I need to check whether x number lies in it or not.

Comment: 3 & 1 really returns boolean? I do not believe. This is bitwise AND so should return numeric value, looks like you missed second symbol & because you mentioned boolean gates

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing two bitmasks in SQL to see if any of the bits match](http://stackoverflow.com/q/143712/90527), [& operator in a SQL Server WHERE Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/q/670230/90527)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server also supports bitwise Operators:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx

Example:

```
DECLARE @isValid bit 
SET @isValid = 3 & 1
```