# Compare bitmasks in the H2 database

Tags: sql, h2

Is there a way to compare bitmasks in the h2 database, similar to what has been asked in [Comparing two bitmasks in SQL to see if any of the bits match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143712/comparing-two-bitmasks-in-sql-to-see-if-any-of-the-bits-match) ?

Having a table of users with different roles, I'd like to select all users that are programmers.

```
  User Table
  ----------
  ID  Username  Roles
  1   Dave      6
  2   Charlie   2
  3   Susan     4
  4   Nick      1

  Roles Table
  -----------
  ID  Role
  1   Admin
  2   Programmer
  4   Designer
```

The select should be something like

```
SELECT * FROM UserTable WHERE Roles & 2 != 0
```

I know there is a BIT_AND function in h2 but do not know how to use it.

Comment: In general, I'd recommend a `UserRoles` table that links users to roles using as many rows as necessary, rather than encoding data and then having to work out how to decode it.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused by the BITAND and BIT_AND functions. The select statement should look like

```
SELECT * FROM UserTable WHERE BITAND(Roles, 2) != 0
```